# derivative of supremum is less than derivative of function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $F(t)$ nonnegative smooth function and let $M(t)=\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}F(s)$.

Then $M'(t) \leq | F'(t) |$.

I know this fact only by intution.

I want to prove this explicitly.

i.e., How to prove the following : $$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{M(t+h)-M(t)}{h} \leq |F'(t)|$$

Comment: $M$ is not necessarily differentiable. Take $F(t) = -\sin t$. Then $M$ is not differentiable at $\pi$.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry, We assume $M$ is also smooth.

Comment: Can you share your intuition why this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F(t) < M(t)$ then $M$ is locally constant around $t$ by continuity of $f$ and hence the formula holds.

Otherwise $M(t) = F(t)$.

If $F'(t) < 0$ (this can only happen at $t=0$) then $M$ is locally constant and hence the formula holds.

Hence we have $F'(t) \ge 0$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then for some $\delta>0$, if $h < \delta$ we have ${F(t+h) -F(t) \over h} \le F'(t)+\epsilon$.

Hence $M(t+h) \le F(t)+ (F'(t)+\epsilon) h $ and so
${M(t+h) - M(t) \over h} \le F'(t)+\epsilon $ and taking limits
gives the desired result.